# Every few calls to webservice I get: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Hostname was not verified

Tags: android, android-volley

Every few calls to webservice I get an error: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: Hostname was not verified

Only doing "Force close" in application settings helps to make my application getting results from webservice again.

It is an ssl connection with valid certificate (everything works well on iOS).

I checked this on android 4.1.2, 4.4.4, and on emulator.
Is there sth wrong with Volley library? Where should I search to get some more information to be able to resolve the issue.

I saw that there are similar questions, but answers say to remove verification :/

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

    // Instantiate the cache
    Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(ctx.getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024 * 10); // 10MB cap

    // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
    Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
    queue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
    queue.start();

    future = RequestFuture.newFuture();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(generalAsk);
    JSONObject js = null;

    try {
        js = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, WsUtils.WS_URL + wsAddress, js, future, future);

    queue.add(jsObjRequest);

    try {
        JSONObject response = future.get();

        Gson gs = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        generalResponse = (BaseResponse) gs.fromJson(response.toString(), c);
        return true;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        errorMessage = e.getMessage();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        errorMessage = e.getMessage();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try adding delays in different places in your code, sometimes discrepancies in timestamps etc cause errors, it might help debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was a problem on the server side. After few hours of digging by administrators everything works perfectly. Unfortunately I do not know what they have changed, but surely it was not Android fault.